# PHP - format special characters and display

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can see that `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` convert special characters like & " to `&amp;` `&quot;` which isn't quite I am looking for.

My database table stores text articles that when I fetch and display,
anything that contains special characters do not display in a readable format.

Any PHP (Codeigniter) function that accomplishes this?

**Added**

Sorry for not being so clear about my question.
My case is that I have a word **it's** and this displays as `itâ€™s`

Comment: What *are* you looking for then? What problem do you have exactly? What characters do you define as "special"?

Comment: @deceze it can be any of those special characters. I cannot simply pick one or two as any variery can come up in the future. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you please give an example of a **special** character?

Comment: I recommend this article for reference: http://kunststube.net/encoding/.

Comment: Wait a minute... Your *special* characters (`&` and `"`) are only special in HTML context—they're encoded exactly the same in all popular encodings. Why isn't `htmlspecialchars()` what you are looking for?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario using htmlspecialchars("&") will give me `&amp;`. My case is that I have `it's` and this displays like `itâ€™s`. `<meta charset="utf-8">` solved it!

Comment: Why didn't you say so in the question?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Right, then it's a dupe after all. Too bad you cannot vote again after retracting a vote. Whatever, printing a literal `&` as `&` will generate **invalid HTML**.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited my question so it is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should check the charset of your output. For example use `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
in your html-document. *[[reference](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#quicklookup)]*.

Answer (score -1):

Try `base64_encode()` it.

```
$newStr = base64_encode("some texrt");
```

And by read, use `base64_decode()`.

Set your mysql database to utf8:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```