# Jquery Autocomplete Search Box

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete JS script for search side of my website but I think something is missing;

Our alphabet has Ç, Ş, Ö, Ğ, Ü and İ letters, also auto-complete script can work with this letters but there is a problem. For example; I have 2 datas like **Çi**çeksepeti and **Ci**dera and I wrote "Çi" on search input, system should just show me "Çiçeksepeti" but it shows "Cicera" too. I think it is not recognizing difference between Ç and C (Also it happens Ş and S, I and İ, U and Ü, O and Ö - shortly with all letters with dots)

You can find my autocomplete.js file [here](http://birlikbilisim.net/jquery.autocomplete.js);  (Autocomplete - jQuery plugin 1.0.2)

Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: I think its related to MySQL not jQuery...

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I solved it. I changed table's "utf8_turkish_ci" and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Often your encoding is wrong. Try this: [PHP - format special characters and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230550/php-format-special-characters-and-display/18230659#18230659)

UTF-8 should display everything in the right way. Sometimes special fonts dont support every sign. So perhaps take a look there.